# How to get callback or fallback or webhook after payment success / fail or cancel

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payment, upi

I have implemented this code for open payment app like GPay, PhonePe, Paytm. I'm able to make open specific application with pre-filled data like merchant code, amount etc and I'm able to make payment as well. but I'm not getting anything like callback, fallback or webhook kind of things.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func action_proceedBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let paValue = "xxxxxxxxxx@ybl"
    let pnValue = "PhonePeMerchant"
    let trValue = "20230414"
    let mcValue = "0000"
    let tnValue = "20230414"
    let amValue = "1"
    let cuValue = "INR"
    let str = "paytmmp://upi/pay?pa=\(paValue)&pn=\(pnValue)&tr=\(trValue)&tn=\(tnValue)&am=\(amValue)&cu=\(cuValue)&mc=\(mcValue)"      
    guard let urlString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    else {
      return
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString)
    else {
      return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
  }
}
```

### Edited

In my application there are multiple merchants. When customer click on any merchant and make payment, Payment must be go to merchant directly. Not via razorpay, paytm or any third party provider. I can only use UPI payment. No credit, debit, netbanking needed.

Comment: Have you completed steps iv) and v) under "API Based App Invoke on iOS" - https://business.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/non-sdk-based-integration?ref=allInOneSdk ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for very quick response. I don't want to use any API key based implementation from PayTM or Razorpay or Payu. I want to send payment to merchant on realtime basis.

Comment: If you open any third party app with url scheme, you won't get any callback unless they implement the same on their app. You need to call your backend api to check if payment is realised or not.

Comment: @Arnab For that might be they have to call any webhook kind of things right?

Comment: You are opening the paytm app right?  For them to open your app once the payment is complete, then they need to know how to do so.  The document I linked shows how a registered merchant can add the correct url scheme to their app so that the paytm app can return.  If you aren't using that approach then there is no way to return to your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Return to app is working or not would be fine. I want to know does transaction started SUCCESS | FAIL or CANCEL. The problem is I'm not getting any trigger after payment is completed or fail or cancel. I'm looking for some webhook kind of things. so payment app calls the webhook and I'm calling api from my app on interval of 10 seconds like that. Hope you understand.

Comment: You can configure webhooks and callbacks in your merchant set up; this is also in the paytm documentation. There is no way of specifying the callback or webhook url as part of the url you call.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's something I'm looking for. Let me check with providers.!

Comment: @PareshGami Did you get solution to this? Please suggest, I have exactly the same case as yours, not able to find relavant doc on internet.